# How to get output of pandas .plot(kind='kde')

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, kernel-density

When I plot density distribution of my pandas Series I use

```
.plot(kind='kde')
```

Is it possible to get output values of this plot? If yes how to do this? I need the plotted values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- [`.plot(kind='kde')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) returns an [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) object.
- The raw values can be accessed by `_x` and `_y` method of the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object in the plot.

  - [`ax.get_children()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html) can be checked to verify [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)  is at `[0]`.
  - Technically speaking, `._y` and `._x` are "private" methods, which is discussed in [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.1`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

In [266]:
np.random.seed(2023)  # for reproducibility 
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))  # or df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000))
ax = ser.plot(kind='kde')  # or ax = df.plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]

```py
In [265]:
ax.get_children() # Line2D at index 0
Out[265]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2b10f8322d0>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2b10f7ff3e0>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2b10f69a300>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2b10db33a40>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2b10f7ff410>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x2b10f7ff530>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x2b10f69a2a0>,
 Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
 Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
 Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x2b104c29f40>]
In [264]:
# get the values
x = ax.get_children()[0]._x
y = ax.get_children()[0]._y

plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also directly call the `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde()` function, that's what happens in pandas source code:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L284

Doc for the function is there:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

Comment: The relevant Pandas code has since moved to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.21.x/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1381-L1430

Answer (score 0):

The top answer does not work for me.
The following code works for me.

```
xx = s.plot.density(color='orange', bw_method=0.1, alpha=1)
hist_x = xx.lines[0]._x
hist_y = xx.lines[0]._y
```